# Getting error while passing alphaneumeric value as parameter inside function using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting one error while passing any alphanumeric value inside function using PHP and Javascript.

error:

```
category.php:235 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
    foreach ($listdata as $v) {
        $id = '15rf67';
        $edit = 1;
        $del = 0;
        echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $counter++ . "</td>
            <td>" . $v['cat_title'] . "</td>
            <td>
                <select class='form-control' id='status1' name='status1'  style='height:23px; padding:0px;'>
                    <option value=''>Select Status</option>
                    <option value='1' " . ($v['status'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Enable</option>
                    <option value='0' " . ($v['status'] == '0' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Disable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src='uploads/" . $v['image'] . "' name='pro' border='0' style='width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;' />
            </td>
            <td>
                " . $v['cat_description'] . "
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$edit)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button> 
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''  data-original-title='Delete' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$del)'><i class='fa fa-times'></i> </button>
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }
?>
```

Here i am getting the error in this `<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$edit)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button>` line.when i am setting the $id value like `1,2..` this error is not coming but i need to pass the Alphanumeric value like `15rf67`.Please help me.

Comment: Where in the code you've posted is line 235?

Comment: I have already mentioned the line of code where error is coming.Please check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place quote around $id, something like that

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(\"".$id."\",$edit)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button> 

<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''  data-original-title='Delete' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(\"".$id."\",$del)'><i class='fa fa-times'></i> </button>
```

Comment: you missed the second php variable

Comment: i did as per you but it gave me the another error in the same line.error-`category.php:236 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`.

Comment: @subhra updated answer with both lines, make sure you only replace those lines

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the quotes for the paramters for button function. Its important to quote alpa or alpha-numeric values. I am writing your code with correct quote in it.

```
<?php
    foreach ($listdata as $v) {
        $id = '15rf67';
        $edit = 1;
        $del = 0;
        echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $counter++ . "</td>
            <td>" . $v['cat_title'] . "</td>
            <td>
                <select class='form-control' id='status1' name='status1'  style='height:23px; padding:0px;'>
                    <option value=''>Select Status</option>
                    <option value='1' " . ($v['status'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Enable</option>
                    <option value='0' " . ($v['status'] == '0' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Disable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src='uploads/" . $v['image'] . "' name='pro' border='0' style='width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;' />
            </td>
            <td>
                " . $v['cat_description'] . "
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(\"$id\",$edit)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button> 
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''  data-original-title='Delete' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(\"$id\",$del)'><i class='fa fa-times'></i> </button>
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$edit)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''  data-original-title='Delete' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$del)'><i class='fa fa-times'></i> </button>
```

should be

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(\"$id\",$edit)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''  data-original-title='Delete' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(\"$id\",$del)'><i class='fa fa-times'></i> </button>
```

Comment: How would that work? There must be quotes around $id. Echo start from double quotes in OP's question

Comment: @Pietro : Your line is throwing the syntax error in the same line.

Comment: I edited only the two lines interested, not the entire code of the OP

Comment: @SameerJain you're right! OP is writing a JS value from PHP, he is missing the single quotes around the var.

Comment: I totally used your code still the error is same i.e-`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }.`.

Comment: ok, so just change the quote. as other people stated, change escape the quotes with `\"`

Answer (score 0):

If your `$id` variabile is a string, you have to handle it as a string in Javascript too. Use something like this:

```
onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(\"$id\",$edit)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly ignore all the answers telling you that you only need quotes - after all, what if one day you decide the ID should contain an apostrophe? Everything breaks!

Instead, here's an alternative method:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger outlinedivnone'
    data-placement='top' title='' data-original-title='Delete'
    data-id='".htmlspecialchars($id)."'
    data-action='".htmlspecialchars($del)."'
    onclick='changeOfActionMenu(this)'
><i class='fa fa-times'></i> </button>
```

Your `changeOfActionMenu` function can then be adjusted like this:

```
function changeOfActionMenu(btn) {
    var id = btn.getAttribute("data-id"),
        action = btn.getAttribute("data-action");
    // do stuff
}
```

This is much more flexible, and among other things will allow you to delegate your event handlers and stop using inline handlers - both things you should be doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 "<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green outlinedivnone' data-placement='top' title=''   data-original-title='Edit' onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$edit)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> </button>";
```

`onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu($id,$edit)'` should be `onClick='javascript:changeOfActionMenu(\"$id\",$edit)'`
，because $id is Alphanumeric(string),you need add `""` for the javascript function string param.

Comment: I disagree. This does provide an answer, although for future reference @wakasann, I would recommend not reposting the whole code snippet when only a small part has changed.